# RSync, Copy all images but not directory structure

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to copy all images from many subdirectories into one folder without the current folder structure.

Example:

```
product/v/9/v9315.jpg
product/v/9/v9316.jpg
product/v/9/v9317.jpg
product/v/9/v9318.jpg
product/v/9/v9319.jpg
```

I just want

```
/images/v9315.jpg
/images/v9316.jpg
/images/v9317.jpg
/images/v9318.jpg
/images/v9319.jpg
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
rsync -rt --include "*/" --include="*.jpg" --exclude="*" root@IP:/var/www/dir/media/catalog/product/ . --dry-run --progress
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `find` command to list all the files, then pipe them to `rsync --files-from` like:

```
find ./product/ -type f -regex ".*[.]jpg" |
rsync -t --no-R --files-from=- . images/
```

The `--no-R` flag makes the files go in "images/" instead of subdirectories.